# npm can't be installed

Tags: npm

```
shubham@shubham$ npm
The program 'npm' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install npm
```

```
shubham@shubham$ sudo apt-get install npm
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
npm is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 9 not upgraded.
```

```
shubham@shubham$ npm
The program 'npm' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install npm
```

```
shubham@shubham$ ls
Desktop    examples.desktop  Music      Pictures   tmp
Documents  firstProject      nohup.out  Public     Videos
Downloads  goibibo_ugc       npm        Templates  WebstormProjects
```

Comment: What is output of `apt-cache policy npm`?

Comment: i aslo wrote "hash -r" due to which above command are coming.Before this it was giving npm command not found.

Comment: npm:
  Installed: 1.3.10~dfsg-1
  Candidate: 1.3.10~dfsg-1
  Version table:
 *** 1.3.10~dfsg-1 0
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

Comment: Then it's installed now what is the output of `which npm`?

Comment: shubham@shubham-Vostro-3460:~$ which npm
shubham@shubham-Vostro-3460:~$

Comment: what is the output of `echo $PATH`?

Comment: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games

Comment: `sudo apt-get purge npm`?

Comment: The following packages will be REMOVED:
  npm*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 9 not upgraded.
After this operation, 1,559 kB disk space will be freed.

Comment: (Reading database ... 200332 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing npm (1.3.10~dfsg-1) ...
Purging configuration files for npm (1.3.10~dfsg-1) ...
Processing triggers for doc-base (0.10.5) ...
Processing 4 removed doc-base files...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...

Comment: Dude you are a life saver.thanks.Does this install the latest version of npm?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based to all comments above, try this:

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install npm
```

Comment: didn't work for me