# can't install npm package : E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages

Tags: 18.04, package-management, npm

I tried to install npm package but it still gave the same output :
[check here the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVuih.jpg)

I even try this solution : [npm can't be installed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/641215/npm-cant-be-installed)
but still the same error occured !

plz help me !

Comment: Hi! I already solved my issue look below. But thank you replying my friend !!!

Answer (score 1):

Hi everyone my issue is solved now, so I'm back to you to share with you the solution that I found :
Please follow these steps

```
sudo apt-get remove nodejs npm ## remove existing nodejs and npm packages
sudo apt-get install curl  
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```